# iOS 11 server interaction

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, ios11

In Xcode 9 when I run my code, I am not able to interact with server in iOS 11, I am getting this error:

> (finished with error - code: -1002)

Every thing is working fine in iOS 10.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can provide us some more information about what you are doing...

Answer (score 1):

error code -1002 means NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL or kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL. It indicates that a bad/wrong URL was provided, in most cases, missing http:// from the URL prefix.

Comment: Yes , you are right Zeeshan ...!! Resolve it , this is the issue of iOS 11 , URL is not doing percentage encoding ..!

Answer (score 0):

error code -1002 means that there is some mistake or bad URL (`NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL`)